# Keep track of pages visited

Tags: c#, asp.net, random

I have a quiz app that randomly picks one of 5 pages with the following method:

```
protected void newWindow(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int next = new Random().Next( 5 ) + 1;
        Response.Redirect(string.Format( "Question{0}.aspx", next ));
    }
```

How can I prevent the method from visiting a page already visited?

Comment: why can't you keep track of the page then check against it and have it redirect to the page that was not visited..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this (untested)

```
protected void newWindow(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<int> questions = (List<int>)Session["Questions"];
    if (questions == null)
    {
        questions = new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
    }

    int nextIndex = new Random().Next(questions.Count());
    int next = questions[nextIndex];
    questions.RemoveAt(nextIndex);
    Session["Questions"] = questions;

    Response.Redirect(string.Format( "Question{0}.aspx", next ));
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't 5 in  int nextIndex = new Random().Next(5); be replaced by current list size?

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a session varibale with csv like 1,2,15,12 and check the next against these values.If it exists in the session roll the dice again else display the page and append the current next to session variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Linq;

protected void newWindow(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pagesVisited = (List<int>)Session["Visited"] ?? new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    if (!pagesVisited.Any())
        // the user has visited all quizes

    var index = new Random().Next(0, pagesVisited.Count)
    var next =  index + 1;

    pagesVisited.RemoveAt(index);

    Session["Visited"] = pagesVisited;

    Response.Redirect(string.Format( "Question{0}.aspx", next ));
}
```